# React Native Firebase account not synchronizing when running on devices

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobile

I am new to React Native and Firebase and am running to a problem when I test my application on actual devices and not the emulators.

This is what I am testing:

1. I create a new account on my android phone and another new account on my iphone.
2. My firebase database updates with the new users
3. I logout from both phones
4. I try to login on my android phone with the account I created on my iphone and firebase gives me an error that the account doesn't exist even though it does.
5. I also do the opposite where I try to login with my iphone using the account I created on my android and I get the same error.
6. So all my accounts that I create on iphones I am able to access with iphones and all my accounts I create on android I am able to access on android

They are sharing the same database so I am a little confused why this is happening. It works perfectly on my emulators but not on actual devices. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my authentication code:

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
      //.catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
        //console.log(error);

        /*firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch)); */
  };
};



//for register view create a user
export const createUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_USER });

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
      //.catch((error) => {
        //console.log(error);

        /*firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch)); */
  };
};
```

Comment: can you share some of the code you are using for the account creation process?

Comment: My first guess is that you don't have a catch clause to see if any errors occurred, so maybe the accounts never got created successfully to begin with. Check the Authentication tab on Firebase console to see if that's the case.

Comment: My accounts are created because they appear on firebase whenever I create an account. I will post some of my code.